# Cant stop server. Postgresql

Tags: bash, postgresql

I am a new user of sql and I have a problem with working with local server on my mac.
Firstly, I wanted to stop server using

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop
```

but but bash returns such issue:

```
 waiting for server to shut
 down...............................................................
 failed 
 pg_ctl: server does not shut down
```

I tried to use

```
brew services restart postgresql
```

After this i use

```
 pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres status
```

bash also returns

```
 pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 3036)
```

How can I stop it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try forcing the "fast" mode, which is a little more rude but on a plus note will skip some of the formalities associated with a more polite shutdown.

```
pg_ctl stop -m fast -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Per the docs:

```
Options for stop or restart:
  -m, --mode=MODE        MODE can be "smart", "fast", or "immediate"

Shutdown modes are:
  smart       quit after all clients have disconnected
  fast        quit directly, with proper shutdown
  immediate   quit without complete shutdown; will lead to recovery on restart
```